# BFS Modification For Total Shortest Paths

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was given the following problem as an assignment but it is really confusing me:

> Consider the BFS algorithm. Given a digraph G = (V, E) and a starting
>   vertex s ∈ V, this algorithm computes for each vertex u ∈ V the value
>   d[u], which is the length (number of edges) on the shortest path from
>   s to u. The objective of this problem is to modify the BFS algorithm
>   of class to compute the number of shortest paths from s to each vertex
>   of G.
>
> This can be done in two steps:
>
> **(a)** First run the standard BFS on G, starting from s. Explain how to use the result of this BFS to produce a new digraph G2 = (V 2,E2),
>   where V 2 ⊆ V and E2 ⊆ E, such that every path in G2 that starts at s,
>   is a shortest path in G starting from s, and conversely, every
>   shortest path in G starting from s is a path in G2.
>
> **(b)** Explain how to take the result of part (a) to compute for each vertex u ∈ V , a quantity n[u], which is the number of paths in G2
>   from s to u. (Hint: This can be done by a modification of BFS.) Both
>   of your algorithms should run in O(V + E) time.

For part a I am not quite sure how to use the results from the BFS to produce a new digraph. I don't understand how/in what way it should be formed. Do I use the nodes that were visited to form a new graph? All nodes are visited when doing a BFS, how am I supposed to form a different graph.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

The question `(a)` can be solved by running the BFS normally, but for every edge `(u, v)` you find while doing it, if `shortest-path(u)+1 <= shortest-path(v)` (no matter if `v` was already visited) then `(u, v)` is a directed edge in `G2`.

Also, while doing it, to solve `(b)` you should increase `n[v] += n[u]`. In the beginning, `n[u] = 0` for everyone except `s`, where `n[s] = 1`.

Here is an example Python implementation:

```py
from collections import deque

def bfs(G, s):
    shortest = [float('+Inf')]*len(G)
    count = [0]*len(G)

    shortest[s] = 0
    count[s] = 1

    Q = deque([s])

    while Q:
        u = Q.popleft()
        for v in G[u]:
            if not count[v]: 
                Q.append(v)

            if shortest[u]+1 <= shortest[v]:
                shortest[v] = shortest[u]+1
                count[v] += count[u]
    return count

G = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4],
    [4],
    [4],
    []
]

print bfs(G, 0)
```